# Connect MySQL workbench with MySQL container

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I pulled MySQL container from [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and it is running on my macbook pro as you can see as follow

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
12cd3deaa3f0        mysql:latest        "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   47 hours ago        Up 10 minutes       3306/tcp            mysqldb
```

Then I downloaded the MySQL workbench and I tried to connect it with MySQL container, but it does not work. It shows connection error.

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 192.168.99.102:3306:
Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.99.102' (60)
```

The IP from docker machine is

```
docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100
```

and the port from MySQL is 3306 as you can see above.

To export MySQL port, I tried with the statement

```
docker run -d -P mysql:latest mysqldb
```

It does not work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see this answer in link below, I think that help you with this problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53431294/1939983 Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you ran the container without setting the `-p 3306:3306` parameter. Also, it seems that you mistyped the IP address in of the Hostname in MySQL Workbench. I recommend starting from scratch by following these instructions:

1. Run the mysql server. (Change the password `admin` to anything you want)

`docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin --name mysql -d -p=3306:3306 mysql`

2. get the IP address of the default docker virtual machine by running

`docker-machine ip default`

3. Copy the IP address that you'll get as the result of the previous command. (in your case, it should be 192.168.99.100)
4. Open MySQL Workbench and create a new connection. Paste the IP address that you copied into the "Hostname" field.

You should be all set now.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `-P` binds the exported ports of a container [automatically](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/usingdocker/#running-a-web-application-in-docker) to available ports of the host.

The following command should bind the containers port 3306 to port 3306 of the host. See: [Publish or expose port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port-p-expose)

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest mysqldb
```

Comment: I typed the statement `docker run -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.7.9 dbmysql` and as output I've got `d38a0f208bcda50132d7f6f679c9282b0d90b275610b8d19ac93bf82d94eea43` but can still not access mysql container with mysql workbench. When I typed docker ps it shows me `d6b44992ec77        mysql:5.7.9         "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   3306/tcp            dbmysql`